# python conditional access to list of lists

Tags: python, list

I would like some suggestion on a problem concerning the access of data stored in a list of lists.

My list of lists looks like this:

```
my_list = [['RN1', 200, 0.55], ['RN2', 0.8, 0.44], ['RN3', 0.2, 0.01]]
```

The list is ordered with respect of the third element of the inner lists.

What I want to do is:

1. To check if the third element of the first inner list is greater or equal to 0.9; if yes, i want to create a list containing the first 2 elements of the first inner list

   ```
   my_list[0][2] >= 0.9
   ```

   Which if true would give:

   ```
   new_list = [['RN1', 200]]
   ```
2. If not, I want to add to `my_list[0][2]` element the corresponding element of the second inner list:

   `my_list[0][2] + my_list[1][2]` and check if this value is greater `0.9`.

If yes I want to stop the loop adding to my new_list the first 2 elements of the second inner list:

```
new_list = [['RN1', 200], ['RN2', 0.8]]
```

If not continue adding elements till the threshold of `0.9` is reached.

Of course this is just an example. My real lists can be a lot bigger and the process should be iterative.

I have tried different possibilities but all of them are not working. For example I have done:

```
sum_percentage = 0.0

new_list =[]

    for i in old_list:

        if sum_percentage <= 0.9:

            sum_percentage = sum_percentage + i[2]

        new_list.append([i[0], i[1]])
```

And other variants of this...Now I am stuck.

Any tips?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You've got 2 lines switched. You want to append the item only if `sum_percentage <= 0.9`. You want to add `i[2]` to `sum_percentage` every time.

Comment: Am I interpreting this correctly? The idea is to add the first two elements of the old list to the new list until the sum of the third value(s) of the items in the old list is greater than or equal to .9?

Comment: in your code, the `for` loop is indented too far.

Comment: @Matthew0898 my interpretation is that he wants to add the first two elements of the minimum number of items of the old list that is needed such that the sum of the last element of these items is greater than or equal to 0.9 (taking items starting at the beginning of the old list).  goddamn, that's confusing to write out.

Comment: But you got it perfectly as I wanted. Thanks! I cannot yet vote for contribution since I am new in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This'll do the job for you:

```
sum_percentage = 0.0
new_list = []
for i in old_list:
    new_list.append(i[:2])
    sum_percentage += i[2]
    if sum_percentage >= 0.9:
        break
```

I think it's self-explanatory, but if you're confused about anything, let me know and I'll expand this answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot dbliss. It worked perfectly for me. Now seems so easy :)

Comment: @atalantafugiens, don't forget to accept the answer if you are satisfied with it!